# JodaTime - first day of next weekend

Tags: jodatime

In JodaTime, it is possible to calculate the first day of next weekend ? For example, now is 19.05.2014 (Monday) and first day of next weekend is Saturday 24.05.2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// algorithm valid for ISO-8601-definition of a week
// (every week starting on Monday)

LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); // in system timezone

// move after current weekend
if (date.getDayOfWeek() >= 6) {
  date = date.plusDays(2);
}

// move to next Saturday (your definition of first day of a weekend)
date = date.withDayOfWeek(6);
System.out.println(date); // 2014-05-24 (if today is 2014-05-19)
```